# Dealing with multiple promise objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Noob question but how do I work with Promise objects in these two ways:

Firstly, I'm getting objects from an api call:

```
api.websockets.userdata(a, b);
```

One way to access the data is using functions:

```
function a(data) {
    console.log(data);    
}

function b(data) {
    console.log(data);    
}
```

So here is my question, how do I access the objects in this manner:

```
client.websockets.userData(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b); //b output is undefined
});
```

And an alternative, how do I access them in this manner by passing a parameter:

```
api.websockets.userdata(a("test"), b); //this gives me an error
```

Comment: It's not clear how promises are involved here. You should clarify what the function `api.websockets.userdata()` expects as arguments and what it returns.

Comment: The API probably expects two callbacks cause these callbacks get called at different times.

Comment: We are more likely to be able to help you if you can provide a reference to both the documentation and the source for the `api.websockets` library.  The answer is in there.  One can't tell by just looking at the code you've posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is not possible, as userdata is supposed to get 2 variables.
The second way is possible as defining both functions, previously or in the way.

```
api.websockets.userdata((text)=>{console.log(text)}, (text2)=>{console.log(text2)});
```

Same as

```
api.websockets.userdata(function a(text){console.log(text)},function b(text2){console.log(text2)});
```

Now, i think your question is not well formuled. Your api is responding with some data given 2 parameters (a and b). if you want to access to that result you have to: (if returns a promise)

```
api.websocket.userdata(a,b).then(result=>{//code});
```

where in code you are processing the data objects. if userdata is resolving some JSON with 2 objects, you need to know those Object properties.

Note: This are arrow functions with ECS6